# Is moving shared_ptr better?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, shared-ptr

I have a method

```
structA
{
     shared_ptr<B> m_b;

     // 2 options to set m_b

     void setB1(shared_ptr<B> b)
     {
         m_b = move(b);
     }

     void setB2(shared_ptr<B> const&b)
     {
         m_b = b;
     }
};
```

Which one is better in performance? They both do copies if I call `setB1` as `setB1(b)` other than `setB1(move(b))`. I am more concerned about its performance when b can be nullified and b can only be copied.

My Testing Answers on VC2015:

`setB1` is faster than `setB2`

- by 30% for lvalue b
- by 8%  for rvalue b

Comment: Presumably you intended for the type of `m_b` to be `shared_ptr<B>` and not just `B`.

Comment: These two do different things: copy creates new `shared_ptr` pointing to the same thing, moving nullifies original `shared_ptr`. Rather than about performance, you should think about what your goal is.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus : Moving nullifies the local `b` object which is destroyed upon function exit anyway.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus They both do copies if I call `setB1` as `setB1(b)` other than `setB1(move(b))`. I am more concerned about its performance, for example when b can be nullified.

Answer (score 0):

The difference in performance is going to be tiny here.

One of them creates a copy into the argument, then moves out of it.

The other refers to an external copy in the argument, and copies out of it.

If you call the first with a shared ptr creating function (like `make_shared`), you'll get 1 move and 0 copies and 1 trivial destroy.  For the second, you get 0 moves and 1 copy and 1 non-trivial destroy.

If you call the first just passing in some random shared ptr by value, you get 1 copy and 1 move and 1 trivial destroy.  In the second, you get 1 copy and 0 moves.

Copying a shared ptr is an atomic increment.  Trivial destroy is a branch.  Non-trivial is a branch and an atomic decrement.  Moving a shared ptr is just setting some pointers.

Comment: The reason I downvoted is the unsupported assertion that "The difference in performance is going to be tiny". I've seen that shared_ptr can add significant overhead in some cases, mostly because copying the shared_ptr causes atomic operations that can hit both single and multi-thread performance. OP' small perf test reflects that. Moving the shared_ptr is clearly preferable when possible.

Comment: @aber I ipvoted yours for the same reason.  Except unless you probably shouldn't normally be using shared ptr if almost every use is a creation use.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

**The answer is Yes, and setB1 is generally better.**

- Copying a shared-pointer makes expensive (slow) atomic increment/decrement operations on the reference count.
- Moving a shared-pointer is almost free and is basically just copying a pointer non-atomically (could be a single assembly instruction).

In your sample, `setB1` provides the user the choice to either move or copy the shared_ptr, allowing for optimal performance when a move is possible for the user, while `setB2` forces a copy.

See a detailed explanation for the performance difference here:
[Why would I std::move an std::shared_ptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41871115/why-would-i-stdmove-an-stdshared-ptr)