# Instantiating a pointer and passing it to two Queues to be consumed by two Threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, queue

I have some code where a thread callback effectively generates some data and writes it to a queue to be consumed by another thread looking something like this

```
auto data_ptr = std::make_shared<DataFrame>();
data_queue_.write(std::move(data_ptr));
```

I know it was written this way as to avoid copies when reading and writing from the queue. I need to instantiate another thread to consume and do some work with this data. Will doing something like this even be logical

```
# Adding this
custom_queue_.write(std::move(data_ptr));
```

Does that mean that the object only gets deleted when it gets pulled out of both of the threads reading from this queue and then only the data_ptr memory allocated gets deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does that mean that the object only gets deleted when it gets pulled out of both of the threads reading from this queue and then only the data_ptr memory allocated gets deleted?

No it doesn't.  The first use of `std::move` will 'rob' `data_ptr` and the second is, effectively, UB.

Don't be afraid to copy a `std::shared_ptr`.  It is a cheap operation and doesn't copy the underlying data.  In fact, that is the whole idea behind `std::shared_ptr` - to share ownership of whatever it points to, with the object being deleted when the last `shared_ptr` goes out of scope.

---

If you're *desparately* worried about performace (which I am not) then you could pass `data_ptr` to `data_queue_.write` by value (thus making a copy) and to `custom_queue_.write` by reference (thus not making a copy).  In neither case is `std::move` appropriate or useful.

But code like this is fragile.  I strongly recommend you keep things simple and pass `data_ptr` by value in both cases.  This is how `shared_ptr` is meant to be used.  People don't talk about modern C++ having value semantics for nothing.

Comment: Note that you may still have `data_ptr` hanging out in scope somewhere keeping the object alive after the threads have ended.

Comment: @user4581301 Need to see more context to answer that one., but if it's existing code ten it's probably OK.

Comment: Yup. And the solutions (tighter scope, call to `reset`, ...) if it's a problem are plentiful and simple.

Comment: So i should copy the shared pointer first and do an std move of that copy to the second queue? When you say copy, you dont actually mean a deep copy but a soft copy (reference) yes?

Comment: No, just pass it by value to both threads, thus giving each thread a copy which goes out of scope when the thread ends.  That is the concept of shared ownership of the pointed-to object that I was talking about.

Comment: I could, but it isn't code I wrote (the first queue). I am trying to rationalize why std::move was used then actually.

Comment: No reason, that I can see.  With only one thread it is harmless (unless you subsequently want to use `data_ptr` in the main thread), but with two or more threads it's a problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41871115/why-would-i-stdmove-an-stdshared-ptr
Moving a shared pointer is 100x more efficient?

Comment: Added a rider to my answer.  Firstly, I really doubt that 100x is the real figure on modern architectures, and secondly the performance penalty, in real terms, is almost certainly insignificant anyway.