# Is this proper usage of std::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, move, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I was wondering if the following is correct usage of a `std::shared_ptr`.
All I want to do with the originally created pointer is add it onto the vector on `class A`,
which will be later on retrieved

```
class A
{
public:
   void AddToVec(std::shared_ptr<B> b)
   {
      myVec_.push_back(b);
   }

   std::vector<std::shared_ptr<B>> GetVec()
   {
      return myVec_;
   }
private:
   std::vector<std::shared_ptr<B>> myVec_;
}
```

Then on `main`, a pointer is created and passed with the following way

```
int main()
{
   A a;

   std::shared_ptr<B> ptr = std::make_shared<B>();
   a.AddToVec(std::move(ptr));
}
```

1. Is the usage of the `std::move` correct on the main function?
2. Is it okay to simply create the `std::shared_ptr` on `main` and move ownership using the `AddToVec` function?

Comment: The `std::move()` isn't necessary.

Comment: Returning a vector of shared_prr by value is rather expensive.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ necessary for that? For successful compilation? Yes, the copy will suffice, but it simply does different things when we apply the `move` and when we don't.

Comment: @Fureeish could that be optimized using `void AddToVec(std::shared_ptr<B>&& b)`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - But that *would* make the move necessary. A value parameter is a sink for whatever value category.

Comment: Ah, OK. I am a bit rusty, and never used && that much at all :-)

Answer (score 3):

> Is the usage of the `std::move` correct on the main function?

Yes, it is correct. If you do not use the `std::move`, it will also compile; however, it increases the reference count of `std::shared_ptr`.

---

> Is it okay to simply create the shared ptr on main and move ownership using the `AddToVec` function?

It is correct in the sense, you do not want to [increment the reference count of the `std::shared_ptr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41871115/why-would-i-stdmove-an-stdshared-ptr).
The same you need inside `AddToVec`, as the `b` is lvalue reference inside the function scope. Therefore, you need to explicitly `std::move`  into the `myVec_` as follows:

```
void AddToVec(std::shared_ptr<B> b)
{
    myVec_.push_back(std::move(b));
}
```

Also note that the `GetVec` will return each time a copy of the member `myVec_`, which you might not want. Therefore, you might need one or both the following

```
// non-const reference to the member
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<B>>& GetVec()
{
    return myVec_;
}

// const reference to the member
const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<B>>& GetVec() const /* noexcept */
{
    return myVec_;
}
```